# Theory on how to break the speed of light

Tags: faster-than-light, order-of-magnitude, scales

I am 14 years old and I think I have a good grasp on physics but I have a question.  Imagine you were to shrink everything in the universe (except for yourself) down to the size of an atom and it was on your finger.  Now, if you move your hand, would everything in the shrunken "universe" be going faster than the speed of light?

Comment: A common mistake is thinking that the speed of light is a technical limitation. As a result, many people, including you, think of creative ways to bypass this limit. You think that there is such a speed that is faster than ligh and we just need to get creative to achieve it. This is incorrect. There is no such a speed in our spacetime. It is counterintuitive, unless you study hyperbolic geometry, but let me give you a parallel. Can we move farther to the North from the North Pole? No. Is it a tachnical limitation that we could creatively overcome? No. Such a place simply doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had an atom-sized object with the mass of the universe, it would be a black hole.  With it on your fingertip, you'd be within its event horizon.  Hypothetical physics questions just stopped being the most pressing matter in your mind.

Also, moving it would be extremely difficult due to its huge mass.

Ignoring the above, the fact of the matter is that you have a very small object, not a very large object that you can magically move around very fast.  Light speed barriers remain intact.